# how post image to api in flutter

Tags: json

{
"_id": "62bc7b32160947df9d338199",
"day": "2022-06-29T15:35:33.968Z",
"examination": false,
"patientID": "P29956741876655",
"expired": false,
"medicalPic": {
"fieldname": "medicalPic",
"originalname": "c9.PNG",
"encoding": "7bit",
"mimetype": "image/png",
"destination": "uploads/",
"filename": "medicalPic-1656519474545-25074610.PNG",
"path": "uploads/medicalPic-1656519474545-25074610.PNG",
"size": 31110
},
"__v": 0
}

Comment: You are sharing an API request, your question is not clear, can you edit your question with what you are trying to do, what have you tried so far and whats the problem you are facing ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.